# Reusing the same ListView to display different data

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, listadapter

`ListViews` have always been my weak point and right now I am practicing putting a `Listview`, within a `Listview`.  Anyway, I first call my `ListView` at the start of my program and it loads it with an array saved in my `strings.xml`:

```
String[] departments = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.departments_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                departments));
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

What I want to do is update this `ListView` with a new array of values each time a list item is clicked.  The reason why I am trying to do it this way is because I plan on having  27 different arrays with different values for each position, and I feel it would be lighter on my resources if instead of making a `ListView` for each array of items, I would update this one `ListView`. I know I am probably not doing this the most efficient way, but if there is another way of implementing my idea please tell me.

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        try {


    //It is here that i dont know what to do, I was going to call 
//the Listview the same way i did previously using my setlistadapter, 
//but i kept getting errors about the code being undefined


                            String[] listitems1 = getResources().getStringArray(
                                    R.array.items_array);

                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        try {
                      //The listview will be changed again here
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                };

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong( if I understand what are you doing). Instead of replacing the adapter of the `ListView` every time the user clicks(and simply setting a new adapter should work) a element in the initial list you should start a new activity passing the clicked position and in your new activity set the adapter on a `ListView` with the correct array based on that position.

A small example:

Main class:

```
/**
 * The main class with the initial 27 items array.
 */
public class Class1 extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // start the second activity that will show our array depending on the
        // position clicked
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Class2.class);
        // put the position in the Intent so we can know in the other activity
        // what array to load.
        i.putExtra("pos", position);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // I just used a simple array of 2 items, you'll load your 27 items
        // array
        String[] items = { "1", "2" };
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    }

}
```

Secondary activity that will show the array based on the previously selected position:

```
public class Class2 extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // get the Intent that started the activity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // find out what position did that other activity send to us.
        int position = i.getIntExtra("pos", -1);
        // load the ListView with an adapter based on the array that you
        // want(according to that position)
        if (position == 0) {
            // the first element in the main list
            String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a1);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        } else if (position == 1) {
            // the second element in the main list
            String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a2);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        } else {
            // etc
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If i start a new activity for each array i want to put in a listview, then that would result in me having about 27 extra classes?  Is that bad? i always thought i was suppose to try to minimize everything as much as possible

Comment: @TheObliviator My answer was for the case when you have a main list with 27 items and for each of those 27 items you have another array of values that you want to also show in a list(this is what I understood and no you don't have 27 activities you just have one main activity and one activity to show the array corresponding to the clicked position, I can give you an example). If this is not what you want, you should edit your question an better explain what you want.

Comment: That is exactly what i want, And im going to try and look into it some more when i come home from school, but yes an example or pseudo code of some sort will help alot

Comment: @TheObliviator I've added a small example.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of using a `BaseAdapter` and setting it as the list adapter
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: Instead of using the `ArrayAdapter` you could extend the `BaseAdapter` and that will make you more controlling over the data , that's If I understood the question clearly from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Luksprog's answer is indeed correct, and it is very useful for lists many levels deep (you do not put limits, just keep spawning new activity instances with the proper list loaded)

BUT

If your list isn't more than 2 levels deep you can use ExpandableListActivity instead of ListActivity which is basically an enhanced version of the single-level list you're using which natively handle group collapsing/expanding and therefore you do not need the spawn of a new activity for each sublevel.

again note that this approach works only for lists which do not go deeper than 2 levels

- [ExpandableListActivity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html)
- [ExpandableListView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)
- [ExpandableListAdapter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) - you should be fine with the BaseExpandableListAdapter implementation

And here you have some nice example from Google itself:

```
public class ExpandableList3 extends ExpandableListActivity {
    private static final String NAME = "NAME";
    private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";

    private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);
            curGroupMap.put(NAME, "Group " + i);
            curGroupMap.put(IS_EVEN, (i % 2 == 0) ? "This group is even" : "This group is odd");
            //filling with dummy data...
            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                children.add(curChildMap);
                curChildMap.put(NAME, "Child " + j);
                curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN, (j % 2 == 0) ? "This child is even" : "This child is odd");
            }
            childData.add(children);
        }

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
            );
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks You both gave me really good answers, and thanks for the information about ExpandableListActivity, im going to start using that more often